# How to make a recursive menu from Gallery on Screen in PowerApps?

Tags: recursion, sharepoint, powerapps

I have a problem of the following nature.

I need to click on the menu item to go to the submenu without leaving the current screen, like in the screen below:

[image: Screen]

Here is the tree view with the controls:

[image: Tree view]

The data is obtained from Sharepoint.

[image: SharePoint data]

In Gallery the Items property has currently this value:

```
Filter(Objects;'Parent'="0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement that logic by storing the value of the "current parent" in a context (or global) variable, and every time you select the button to go "to a different folder", you would update that variable to point to the new ID.

Those are some of the properties to update:

```
App.OnStart: Set(CurrentParent; 0)
Gallery.Items: Filter(Objects; 'Parent' = CurrentParent)
NextArrow.OnSelect: Set(CurrentParent; ThisItem.ID)
NextArrow.Visible: !IsBlank(LookUp(Objects; 'Parent' = ThisItem.ID))
BackButton.OnSelect: Set(CurrentParent; LookUp(Objects; ID = CurrentParent; 'Parent'))
BackButton.Visible: CurrentParent <> 0
```

You can see this logic in the app from https://carlosfigueira.blob.core.windows.net/public/StackOverflow54822913.msapp; to open it, download it locally, then go to https://create.powerapps.com, select Open, Browse and choose the file that you downloaded.